# Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0 in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, xamarin.android, stripe-payments

I am working on Xamarin Android. I am implementing stripe for payment but when I hit the stripe API the following exception is caught

> Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please initiate HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.

What can be done to remove the error?

P.S. The same code is working absolutely fine in Xamarin IOS.

Here is my code:

```
    async Task<StripeCustomer> GetCustomer(string cId)
        {
        AppLog.WriteLogD(TAG, "Getting Customer...");
        var customerService = new StripeCustomerService();
        StripeCustomer stripeCustomer = null;
        try
        {
            Task<StripeCustomer> getCustomerTask = customerService.GetAsync(cId);
            stripeCustomer = await getCustomerTask;
            //Console.WriteLine(stripeCustomer.StripeResponse.ResponseJson);
            AppLog.WriteLogD(TAG, "Customer: " + stripeCustomer.Description, "(" + stripeCustomer.Email + ")");
        }
        catch (StripeException e)
        {
        AppLog.WriteLogD(TAG, "Error Type:" + e.StripeError.ErrorType);
            AppLog.WriteLogD(TAG, "Message:: " + e.StripeError.Message);
        }
        return stripeCustomer;
    }
```

Comment: Which `HttpClient Stack` have you selected? And on which Android device you are testing your app (Android version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by:

1. Go to Project Options
2. In General tab, set HttpClient Implementation to AndroidClient Handler and SSL/TLS implementation to Native TLS 1.2+ which is the default option but incase you had switched to TLS 1.0

Answer (score 2):

According to Android Documentation, [TLS 1.2 is supported by API Level 16 or higher](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)

To activate it you should:

1. Set minimum Android version to API Level 16
2. Set SSL/TLS implementation to 1.2 in Project settings -> Android Parameters -> SSL/TLS Implementation